# past two-dimensional array as an own-dimensional array to a function in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I will pass a two-dimensional Array as a one-dimensional Array to a function in C

I know what I must doing and what the visible result is. But I don't know what's going on in the background. I passed it like so function((char*)array)  and received so function(char *array). What I know is that I make a pointer that can hold the addresses of characters and I give them the array, then in my function header, I dereference it to have the Value and not the address of the first value of the first inner array. What makes me a bit confused is why I can't pass it like a simple one-dimensional array.  Than I have learned when I past an one-dimensional array to a function like function(array) and receive, function(array[]) C makes automatically a pointer to the first value of the array. Why not by passing a two-dimensional array?
What I think is going on hear is that I give the function the two-dimensional array C makes a pointer to the first value, hear it is one of the inner arrays, but now C has no information about that, and I must give them the information that I stored some characters in the inner array. I am right?

Thanks for helping and funny coding, everyone.

Comment: "Flattening" a 2-D array by treating it as a 1-D array via a pointer is technically against the rules if you access elements beyond the row that the pointer is pointing within.

Comment: *I will pass a two-dimensional Array as a one-dimensional Array to a function in C*  Please post your actual code, as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please post your code - even if it isn't work - instead of describing your code with words.

Comment: Is your "2D" array a "pointer to pointer". If YES then it is not 2D array and it is not possible to flatten it this way

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to pass 2d array as a pointer to a single dimensional array. It will prevent UB when you access it as a singe dim array

```
void printa(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*arr)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("%03d ", arr[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void inita(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*arr)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            arr[row][col] = rand() % 1000;
}

int main(void)
{
    
    int arr[10][5];
    size_t rows, cols;
    
    srand(time(NULL));

    int (*arr1)[cols = rand() % 20] = malloc(sizeof(*arr1) * (rows = rand() % 10));

    inita(10,5,arr);
    printa(10,5,arr);

    printf("\n\n");

    if(arr1)
    {
        inita(rows, cols, arr1);
        printa(rows, cols, arr1);
    }
    free(arr1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vhPKfhnbb

REMEMBER! `type **x` is not a 2D array

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica aren't they?

Comment: @gupr Oops, just had to scroll down.